# How to solve Grails resource not found error for a plugin?

Tags: grails

I have set up an extremely simple Grails project. I am learning the test framework. I ran:

```
grails test-app
```

The unit test worked as expected. The integration test phase, however, reported an error:

```
  Starting integration test phase ... 
  2011-05-30 10:10:51,700 [main] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /plugins/jquery-1.6.1.1/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js 
  2011-05-30 10:10:51,719 [main] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /plugins/jquery-1.6.1.1/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.1.js
```

I verified that I have the jquery plugin installed, and that the missing files are indeed in ~/.grails/plugins. Is there some configuration setting that I have missed?

Comment: Have tried running 'grails clean' prior to test-app?

Comment: Try 'grails refresh-dependencies' in your project directory.

Answer (score 1):

What worked with me was replacing

```
<g:javascript library="jquery"/>
```

with

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, check the plugin-folder and do a 'grails clean' that worked like a charm for me!