# FullCalendar in Grails

Tags: json, grails, fullcalendar

I need same help to populate the JSON on a calendar. The JSON is this:

> {
>   "start":"",
>   "end":"",
>   "title":"",
>   "summary":""
>   }

I return this JSON;

```
def createJSONEvent = {
    def json="["
        json+="{"
        json+="title:\"fede\","
        json+="start:'2012-05-01T22:00:00',"
        json+="end:'2012-05-01T22:30:00',"
        json+="allDay: false,"
        json+="url:\"${request.contextPath}/calendar/index/1\","
        json+="backgroundColor:'blue',"
        json+="textColor:'black'"
        json+="}"       
    json+="]"
    render json
}
```

And I want to show it with this HTML code:

```
<fullcal:calendar id="cal">
 theme: true,
 header: {
 left: 'prev,next today',
 center: 'title',
 right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
 },
 columnFormat: { week: 'ddd d/M' },
 timeFormat: 'HH:mm{ - HH:mm}',
 selectable: true,
 selectHelper: true,
 editable: true,
 events:${include(controller:"calendar", action:"createJSONEvent")}
</fullcal:calendar>
```

And nothing happens. The console show:

> 2012-05-18 12:33:13,319 [http-8080-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /plugins/full-calendar-1.5.1.0/css/fullcalendar.css
>   2012-05-18 12:33:13,324 [http-8080-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /plugins/full-calendar-1.5.1.0/js/fullcalendar.min.js
>   2012-05-18 12:33:14,082 [http-8080-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /plugins/full-calendar-1.5.1.0/css/fullcalendar.print.css

What am I missing?

Comment: Even if your English is bad you can still get help here as long as people can tell what you are asking. But this question is not very clear. We can't tell what it is you want to do, and we can't tell what problem you are having. Can you show us the code of what you have tried already?

Comment: yes, i want to show events from a json, the code is this,
 def getCalendarByName(def calendar) {
  def cal = Calendar.findById(calendar)
  ArrayList events = new ArrayList()
  String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm"
  cal.events.each {a ->
   JSONObject jsonEvent = [:]
   jsonEvent.id = a.id
   jsonEvent.summary = a.summary
   jsonEvent.start = a.startDate
   jsonEvent.end = a.endDate
   jsonEvent.description = a.description
   events.add(jsonEvent)
  }
  JSONObject json = [:]
  json.id = cal.id
  json.name = cal.name
  json.events = events
  return json
 }

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. There is a link under your question that says 'edit'. Please click that and include that information in your question. It is too hard to read in a comment.

Comment: Just FYI: there is an easier way to build a JSON response in Grails. Grails converters can convert many Objects for you easily. For example the body of createJSONevent could look like this: `render [ title: "fede", start: "2012-05-01T22:00:00", end: "2012-05-01T22:30:00", allDay: false, url: "${request.contextPath}/calendar/index/1", backgroundColor: "blue", textColor: "black" ] as JSON` Which is neater and quicker. See: http://grails.org/Converters+Reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181579/how-to-solve-grails-resource-not-found-error-for-a-plugin) suggests a 'grails clean' might help. Have you tried this?